# XAMPP (LAMPP) on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-touch, mysql, php, xampp

Can I install and run XAMPP (LAMPP) on Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 10 in order to host a local website (that needs PHP and MySQL)?

Comment: I think `apt-get` works in Ubuntu Touch, so you can `apt-get install lamp-server`.

Comment: I tested apt-get install lamp-server^ and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Is it XAMP -or- LAMP?  They are -not- the same...

Comment: Sorry, LAMP(`lamp-server^`) works, as well as PhpMyAdmin. I did not test XAMP(P) (by apachefriends.org).

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` doesn't work anymore on Ubuntu Touch (OTA-22), write protection.

If you are careful with the space `df -h` you can (**Warning: this could brick your phone!**) remount the root `/` folder with:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

and then install the relevant packages, e.g. `apache2`, etc, using `apt` as:

```
sudo apt install apache2
```